# Laravel socialite authentication instance of Laravel\Socialite\Two\User given Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am tired of this error, i have set up everything perfectly.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('facebook', ['as' => 'facebook', 'uses' => 'UserControllers\UserController@facebookLogin']);
Route::get('callback', ['as' => 'callback', 'uses' => 'UserControllers\UserController@callBack']);
```

**Function:**

```
public function facebookLogin()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from facebook.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function callBack()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect('/home');

    // $user->token;
}
```

> $user = User::create(['name'=>$user->getName(), 'email'=>$user->getEmail()]);

When i create user in the database like this `auth()->login($user);` does not throw any error. but using only `fb` returned object it throws this error. Now this is clear i should use `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;` this in my user model. so found a solution and added these lines to `User` Model.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
class User extends Eloquent  implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;
```

but it still throws the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Socialite `user()` and your `User` model are two different things.

Your `User` model is related to the information stored in your database while the `user` returned through `socialite` is related to the information given to you by Facebook (or another provider)

You can find more information on logging a user through Sociliate [Laravel 5.2 Socialite Facebook Login](http://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.V3lxs_l96Uk)